# Передача закрытого ключа пользователя при клиент-серверное архитектуре

Tags: javascript, c#, безопасность, клиент-сервер, шифрование

Подскажите, пытаюсь реализовать приложение для чата на основе клиент-серверной архитектуры. То есть схема передачи сообщения такая: Клиент 1 -> Сервер -> Клиент 2. Но так как я хочу приложение сделать хоть чуточку безопасным, то принял решение реализовать еще и сквозное шифрование. И вот в чем мой вопрос: после генерации пары (открытый-закрытый) ключей для ассиметричного шифрования на клиенте я спокойно могу передать открытый ключ в базу данных на сервере (чтобы после отправить этот ключ другому клиенту для шифровки сообщений) по незащищенному каналу связи, но я не могу того же самого сделать с закрытым ключом, так как в этом случае теряется вообще вся суть шифрования. И логичным решением было бы оставить закрытый ключ в файлике на ПК клиента, но в таком случае, если клиент зайдет в свой аккаунт с нового устройства, то он просто не сможет получить доступ к своим предыдущим перепискам. Как в современных приложениях решается этот вопрос? Потому что я уже сломал буквально всю голову и не могу придумать решения. Заранее спасибо за ответы :)

Comment: Если шифрование сквозное и сервер не в курсе текста сообщений, то вы можете рассмотреть синхронизацию между несколькими устройствами одного юзера, при условии что они онлайн одновременно. Они также могут открытыми ключами поменяться для синхронизации.

Comment: Обычно при сквозном шифровании принцип следующий: 1) от клиента-1 передается клиенту-2 открытый ключ по открытому каналу (напрямую или через сервер, не важно) 2) клиент-2 генерирует ключ для симметричного шифрования, шифрует его с помощью открытого ключа и передает клиенту-1 3) клиент-1 получает ключ, расшифровывает и дальше передача между клиентом-1 и клиентом-2 идет по симметричному шифру. Закрытый ключ никуда не передается, остается только у владельца.

Comment: В исходниках какого-нибудь телеграм-клиента можно покопаться.